# How to pass image using jquery asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi I am new to ASP and wondering how to pass an image from the `input file` using `jquery ajax`.

I am supposed to pass the path and get the image in the server side? is it possible?
or are there any alternative on it?

what I am doing is that I want to upload a photo while checking if the user is currently in session.
I used ajax so I dont refresh my page everytime I hit the upload button.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Upload.aspx/uploadPhoto',
    data: "{ ???? }", <-- what Should I put it here??
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Is it the right way to upload a photo while checking the session in the webmethod?

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Comment: lots of different uploader scripts that also provide server connectors for various languages/frameworks. Just google ajax upload

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('#youruploadbuttonid')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Upload.aspx/uploadPhoto',
    data: formData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#youruploadbuttonid')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Upload.aspx/uploadPhoto',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```